# Desempenho do Long Polling com PHP, MySQL e Ajax

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, longpolling

Estou desenvolvendo um site em PHP, e utilizando as técnicas de Long Polling para as notificações em tempo real.

Estou fazendo com que o script espere 50 segundos por uma resposta, e não obtendo uma, em 2 segundos ele volta a perguntar, para dar maior rotatividade de conexões, como os grandes sites fazem.

Já testei com algumas conexões ativas na minha máquina, abrindo abas e navegadores diferentes ao mesmo tempo, e cada uma abre um processo diferente no servidor

As dúvidas são as seguintes:

1. cada processo desse equivale a um usuário ativo?
2. esse método puxa muito das capacidades do servidor, caso tenha muitos usuários ativos?

Pergunto isso pois a hospedagem só libera pra mim espaço para até 30 usuários ativos ao mesmo tempo, e se for isso mesmo, vou precisar de algo que dê bem mais que isso.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Infelizmente long polling e PHP não são bons companheiros.

Para cada browser que está em long polling a solicitar um pedido, um processo PHP está a ser executado. Isto quer dizer que não só tens um processo por utilizador, como poderás ter vários processos por utilizador se o utilizador tiver várias tabs ou janelas abertas no teu site.

Mesmo que a configuração do PHP esteja optimizada para não sugar muitos recursos, não é facilmente escalável, principalmente num alojamento partilhado. Ainda por cima com o limite de utilizadores, cada processo em long polling vai impedir que outro utilizador esteja a aceder ao site, se atingires o limite de 30.

Comment: Entendi... de todo jeito usando PHP corro esse risco né. Eu acho que teria mesmo que usar algum outro método de Websocket

Comment: @IsaiasLima Sim, existem outras coisas que se adaptam melhor a esse tipo de programação do que o PHP.